# Autologin Xenial/OpenBox WITHOUT Lightdm

Tags: 16.04, openbox, auto-login

I installed the Ubuntu MINI.ISO on VMWare with OpenBox and would like to set my user on autologin, but **I don't want to install lightdm**, cause I think I don't need it. 
All solutions I read until now use lightdm. Is there a way without it?
FYI: **I'm a enthusiastic linux rookie...
Thanks folks.**

Edit: for a better understanding: this machine does not need any desktop apps like office tools or web browser etc. It's only purpose is to start as fast as possible without breaks for user data input or s.th. else and show a graphical application written in GTKsharp.
Perhaps OpenBox is not the right GUI, I'm thankful for suggestions to solve that topic.

Comment: *What* components did you install? Did you install a desktop environment? If so, what desktop environment? If not, what do you mean by "autologin"?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" without any GUI and after that openbox from a terminal. I now want to skip the login prompt automatically with my stored userdata

Comment: Desktop not Server. Would it help to switch to Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic Beaver" ? but without gnome installed I think GDM will not be available? Talking about those mini installations: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: Install a display manager (such as LightDM) if you want to autologin.

Comment: Not very contructive... As I wrote, I would like to avoid lightdm, cause the purpose of that system is to be as lean as possible and to boot as fast as possible. Will think it over thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue:

- Install slim

> apt get install slim

- edit /ect/slim.conf

> default_user "name of user to login"
>
> auto_login yes

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same question but for Ubuntu 20.04
and I found the solution on the [ArchLinux wikiForum](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty#Automatic_login_to_virtual_console)

== Here a step by step ==

**1. edit /etc/systemd/logind.conf**
*that will switch the focus from Terminal tty1 to Terminal tty6 automatically*
set `NAutoVTs=6`

**2. edit /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf**
`sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin YourUsername --noclear %I $TERM
```

`sudo systemctl enable getty@tty1`

**3. edit /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/noclear.conf**
*to keep boot messages on tty1*

```
[Service]
TTYVTDisallocate=no
```

**4. edit ~/.xinitrc**
add `exec openbox-session` at the end of it